# How much higher will I realistically be able to sing with daily practice and dedication?

Tags: vocal-range

I am a baritone, and started trying to improve my range about a year ago. I do not receive any formal training, but I know the basics of what to do and not to do.

I warm up for about 15 minutes before attempting a song that requires me to get out of my comfort zone.

About a year ago when I started singing, my highest note was G above middle C, and this was a huge stretch.

Now, a year on, I can sing an A, one tone higher, but it is a stretch and I fatigue very quickly if I attempt this note, so tend to stay away from it.

I understand this is quite a vague question and everyone is different, but with formal training from a reasonable coach, daily practice, what is a realistic expectation for range improvement in say, 2 years time?

Comment: If you want to ruin your vocal cords, keep going. If you want to learn to sing, get a teacher; don't expect any kind of magical range extension.

Comment: I'm not expecting any magical range extension, no need for the rudeness. Did you even read the question? I literally said "with a reasonable coach"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can anyone learn to sing higher?](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6034/can-anyone-learn-to-sing-higher)

Comment: This is a legitimate question about singing technique. I ought to know; I have a college degree in operatic voice. Please keep this question open.

Comment: It's taken a year to gain a tone. Even with a coach, there is more chance, as Carl says, of wrecking the voice rather than being able to sing much higher. There seems to be little point in the exercise, why?

Answer (score 3):

If you are a baritone and you can sing the "A" above Middle C, then you are at the top of the baritone range, and you should not be surprised if you find it fatiguing. There are many tenors that never get up to the "A" above Middle C. There are only a few operatic baritone roles that require a high "A" (*The Barber of Seville* comes to mind.)

Get a qualified voice teacher for a few lessons, to get an honest appraisal of your vocal technique, and to learn how to sing without creating undue stress on your voice, which causes fatigue. A voice teacher will help you "un-learn" some bad habits and replace them with better technique. Keep practicing daily. I doubt you'll add additional higher notes, but you can learn to sing stronger and longer and more freely without the stress and fatigue, and that will benefit you greatly.